# Get output as string of ConsumerGroupCommand.main()?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to use `ConsumerGroupCommand.main(new String[]{"--bootstrap-server","xxx:9092","--group","consumer3","--describe"});` to get offset metrics,But the method's response type is void.And just the console print the msg

such as:

```
GROUP                          TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             OWNER
consumer3                      ttest                          1          5522143         5522143         0               localhost java2_/ip
consumer3                      ttest                          0          5392302         5392302         0               localhost java new_/ip
```

How i to get the response as a `string`?

Comment: `ConsumerGroupCommand` uses `KafkaConsumerGroupService` internally. Try to use this.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax,KafkaConsumerGroupService also the void method.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax,Any other java api can get the metrics?

Comment: What do you mean by "also the void method" ? KafkaConsumerGroupService is a class and after you instantiated on object of it, it offers you multiple methods that do return stuff, for example `listGroups()` or `describeGroup()`